# React.findDOMNode is not a function?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs

Recently i am working on react.js crud application i like to use react.findDomNode for create record

```
handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        name = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.name).value.trim();
        email = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value.trim();
        address = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.address).value.trim();
        state = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.state).value.trim();
        zip = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.zip).value.trim();
        city = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.city).value.trim();
```

but i face following error how can i reslove it i also use

> ReactDOM.findDOMNode
>   But still have same error 
>   [image]

Comment: shouldn't it be `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [ReactDOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) package.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
const name = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.name).value.trim();
```

But in your case you can use just refs to get value:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = this.refs.name.value.trim(),
          email = this.refs.email.value.trim(),
          address = this.refs.address.value.trim(),
          state = this.refs.state.value.trim(),
          zip = this.refs.zip.value.trim(),
          city = this.refs.city.value.trim();
}
```

Comment: i also try this , but dont get value its send null value

Comment: Can you show me your JSX with inputs?

Comment: handleSubmit: function(e) {e.preventDefault();name = this.refs.name.value,
          email = this.refs.email.value,
          address = this.refs.address.value,
          state = this.refs.state.value, 
 if (!name) {
    return;
  }
  // TODO: send request to the server
  var customer = {
   name: name,